# Travel to Jersey for UK Biometric Resident Permit Holders

Tags: visas, uk, international-travel, islands, channel-islands

I have a UK Biometric Residence Permit under Tier 2 and I want to visit Jersey (not NEW JERSEY, the Jersey between England And France, a tiny island) for a sport event. I am not sure if I will be able to enter and exit Jersey without any additional visa. Does Jersey come under the UK of Great Britain and Northern Ireland?

Comment: Jersey is definitely not part of the UK but has all sorts of special agreements with it and with the European union. Beyond that, I don't know much but I found this: http://www.gov.je/Travel/InformationAdvice/Visitors/Pages/NonEUEEA.aspx It does not provide a straightforward answer but does include a link to contact the relevant authorities.

Comment: @Annoyed The information is there just one page up.

Comment: @Gilles If I chose to post it as a comment, it's because I think the information *isn't* there. But then, if you think this amounts to an answer, the polite thing to do is upvote the comment and/or invite me to post an answer based on it.

Answer (score 4):

Jersey and Guernsey require a valid visa or visa exemption to enter the UK, no more, no less. So if you have a residence permit that allows you to enter the UK, you're good for short stays in Jersey and Guernsey as well (up to 6 months, which also count against your UK time limit as well if applicable). There are no immigration controls between the UK and the Channel Islands.

Official source: [Jersey visa and passport requirements for visitors](http://www.gov.je/Travel/InformationAdvice/Visitors/Pages/VisaPassport.aspx); [Guernsey entry clearance/VISA requirements](http://www.gov.gg/doirequireanentryclearance).

Comment: That was my interpretation as well but I don't find the language so clear-cut. I would still contact them to be sure. I don't find it constructive or responsible to provide such an opinion based only on a website with apparently no personal experience or relevant legal expertise whatsoever.